# Android camera.open() java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I' ve already tried many sources, checked many answer but still i can't understand whats the problem with my code.
I'm trying to have a toggle button with flashlight on/off mode.

```
    package ium.earlywarning;

import ium.earlywarning.widget.GIFView;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    public static String APERTO = "allaperto";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static String LOG_TAG = SecondActivity.class.getName();
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
            {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
            {
                // hide the given tab
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
            {
                // probably ignore this event
            }
        };

        /**
         * Aggiunge i tabs:
         */
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Chiuso").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Aperto").setTabListener(tabListener));
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(APERTO, false))
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

        }

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                // When swiping between pages, select the
                // corresponding tab.
                getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }


    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {
        private boolean mIsTorchPresent = false;
        private Camera mCamera = null;
        private Camera.Parameters mCameraParameters;
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber)
        {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause()
        {


            if (mCamera != null)
            {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            super.onPause();
        }


        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        public void onToggleClicked(View v)
        {
            // Is the toggle on?
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();

            if (on)
            {
                Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");
                mCameraParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");
                mCameraParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParameters);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

            final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            if (!isCameraSupported(pm))
            {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("No Camera");
                alertDialog.setMessage("The device's doesn't support camera.");
                alertDialog.setButton(RESULT_OK, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which)
                    {
                        Log.e("err", "The device's doesn't support camera.");
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////The line:

            mCamera = Camera.open();


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Controllo se è presente la torcia:
            mIsTorchPresent = getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

            // ToggleButton torcia = (ToggleButton)
            // rootView.findViewById(R.id.torcia_btn);

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            final Integer[] gifIDs;

            switch (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1:
                    gifIDs = new Integer[] { R.drawable.sciencebitch,
                            R.drawable.lol1, R.drawable.lol2, R.drawable.lol3,
                            R.drawable.lol4 };
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gifIDs = new Integer[] { R.drawable.sciencebitch,
                            R.drawable.lol1 };
                    break;
                default:
                    gifIDs = new Integer[] { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2 };
            }

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_linearlayout);

            OnClickListener textViewOnClickListener = new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // display the images selected

                    GIFView gifView = (GIFView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_gif);
                    String tvValue = (String) ((TextView) v).getText();
                    gifView.setMovieResource(gifIDs[Integer.parseInt(tvValue)]);
                }
            };

            int i = 0;
            for (int id : gifIDs)
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_numb_tv, null);
                tv.setText(i + "");
                i++;
                // GIFView gv = (GIFView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.thumb_gif,
                // null);
                // gv.setMovieResource(id);
                // gv.setOnClickListener(gifOnClickListener);
                tv.setOnClickListener(textViewOnClickListener);
                linearLayout.addView(tv);

                TextView spacer = new TextView(getActivity());
                spacer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(4, 2));
                spacer.setText(" ");
                linearLayout.addView(spacer);

            }
            return rootView;
        }

        private boolean isCameraSupported(PackageManager packageManager)
        {
            // if device support camera?
            if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

When i run this, i get a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

Inside my android manifest, i've defined these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

i've come up to this https://code.google.com/p/torch/ but the source looks exactly like mine. The exception is thrown on camera.open().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904459/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service

Comment: hi! @iThink already passed throught that question but didn't help :S

Comment: could you add mcamera.open in your onToggleClicked() method if togged is switched on. also surround it with a try/catch statement and check

Comment: I resolved. That damn camera dosen't work in fragment. I've moved all the work related to it in the activity section.

Comment: Camera will work with fragment also.
Check Out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604742/android-camera-preview-in-a-fragment.