# Android - Camera within a fragment

Tags: android, android-camera

I spent a lot of hours trying to take a picture with a SurfaceView and Camera inside of a Fragment.

I have already look other solutions:

- https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment
- [Android Camera preview in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604742)
- [Take photo from camera in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408240)
- [Android Camera preview in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604742)

I have a working code but I have still one big issue:
When I take a picture the saved image is **rotated.**

I have one big constraint:

**- The screen orientation is only portrait.**

Since I can't check my device orientation when I have `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in Manifest I can't rotate by myself the saved image.

In the other hand I know apps like snapchat achieve it so I think is not imposible.
Plus If I use the following code works like a charm!

```
Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
```

But I have to use it on a fragment, and this opens a new activity, right? Probably should I look for official android source code?

I have tried check the EXIF tag but always return 0.

I have tried using MediaStore but always return 0.

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
```

I think the solution is rotate the image but I'm not able get the original orientation of the image.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: This finally solves my problems http://stackoverflow.com/a/15812722/2139691