# How to open camera ONLY in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

Following code opens camera but covers complete screen, and after capturing image it returns to the fragment No signs of clicked image. ( image is safely saved in gallery.  I want to open camera ONLY IN FRAGMENT part. I have copied the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408240/take-photo-from-camera-in-fragment). I just removed 'viewHolder' (4rth line of try()) as I don't know what it was doing. and declared URI variable at top in my code.
I also have tried other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604742/android-camera-preview-in-a-fragment) but they are complicated as I am developing on API 19.

```js
//my declared variables 
 private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    Uri imageUri;


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 100);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
    }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    try {
                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                                .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedImage.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following code opens camera but covers complete screen

Sure. You are launching a third-party camera app, and those usually take over the foreground.

> I want to open camera ONLY IN FRAGMENT part.

Write your own camera code from scratch, using `android.hardware.Camera` and/or the `android.hardware.camera2.*` set of classes. You cannot launch a third-party camera app into a fragment.