# What else to do for making camera work in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to open camera in a fragment. I am using api level 19. Therefore camera library is used instead of camera2. below is my code I tried copying from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) I am unable to open camera in my fragment. Tell me where is the fault. :( Please anyone. It is 2 days since I am trying to open camera.

//code of fragment class named scan

```js
package layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.root.meeransunday.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link scan.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link scan#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class scan extends Fragment {


    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public scan() {
    }


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static scan newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        scan fragment = new scan();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(checkCameraHardware(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
            getCameraInstance();
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);

            container.addView(mPreview);
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);
    }

//

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    public boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
    //

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

//code of camera Exception class as it is from the android //documentation link

```js
package layout;

/**
 * Created by root on 4/12/17.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

//fragment xml named scan

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Camera_preview"
    tools:context="layout.scan"
    android:background="#f5f5dc"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

```js
  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at layout.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:37)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:90)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:195)
                      at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: interp stack at 0x62222000
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4972 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

error log above^^

```js
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.root.meeransunday, PID: 16453
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at layout.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:37)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:90)
                      at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:195)
                      at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Device rivo-phantom_pz15-HB51Q0H9103UXBdisconnected, monitoring stopped.
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Does it generate the error ?

Comment: it does  and the error is at method surface created of cameraException class

Comment: at layout.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:37)

Comment: Please provide error log......

Comment: I have added the log above please check :( @abhilash Maurya

Comment: post your onactivityresuly code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355372/how-to-open-camera-only-in-a-fragment
isnt it solved?

Comment: @aditya Vyas Lakhan  all my code is above related to fragment . then there is my main activity  which does not have overriden a=onactivty . As in tutorial  of android camera use.. They have not asked about it. till time to display camera preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I asked that and followed the guidance to write own code for making camera open in a fragment.  and Now I am stuck here..  I just want to see preview of camera in fragment after follwoing this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I have written complete code and Can you find any of the things like that?? I can't Any help will be great Please

Comment: did you add permissions properly?

Comment: Yes I did @AdityaVyas-Lakhan :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16833289/4407266

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan nothing happened at all. Can you Only tell me. have I called the camera instance and made preview attachment in IF condition  in Oncreate View is Correct?? does it needs to be there?? or some where else??  Just this.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AndroidManifest` add permission for camera like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code wasn't able to find the surface for camera preview.
So in your fragment class you need to define exactly where you want to show your camera preview.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);

     if(checkCameraHardware(getActivity().getApplicationContext())){
        getCameraInstance();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);

        //container.addView(mPreview);--->Remove this line 
        //Add this line
        FrameLayout preview =(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

And Also you need to provide a particular container in layout file as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this could solve your problem......

Comment: If this could ... That will be Realy great @Abhilash Let me check this and will get back to you

Comment: There is almost the same error.  I have updated the error Log above Please can you check